# View kNN classification results in R

Tags: r, knn

I'm trying to see how my training data was classified. I can get the algorithm to run just fine and can see how many observations in my training data were classified as "A" or "B" (my two levels). But I'm trying to see what each individual observation in the training data was classified as. It would be great if I could just append the classification results to the training data as a new column.

Here is what I have so far:

```
head(train,n=5) 
 x  y
1 30 16
2 15  5
3 25 27
4 15 30
5  5 22

head(test,n=5)
  x  y
40 79 80
41 60 78
42 70 53
43 38 72
44  2 53

 cl
 [1] A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B
[39] B
Levels: A B


 library(class)
 results = summary(knn(train,test,cl,k=3))
 results
 A B 
 4 6
```

I'm trying to see which observations in the test data those 4 A's and 6 B's belong to.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
predictions = knn(train,test,cl,k=3)
```

Just don't use summary... it should output a vector of the predicted class for each test observation.